# Haskell: Getting the output of a function to be used as an input to another?

Tags: string, function, haskell, char

I have created the alphabet using the following code;

```
letter :: Char -> [String]

letter 'A' = [" AAA ","A   A","AAAAA","A   A","A   A"]
```

and so on for each letter. Along with another function which capitalises a lowercase letter which is inputted by the user using the following code:

```
capital :: Char -> Char

capital letter
    | ord letter >= ord 'a' && ord letter <= ord 'z' = chr (ord letter + (ord 'A' - ord 'a'))
    | otherwise                                      = letter
```

All I am trying to do is to input `letter 'a'` in lowercase so the program can capitalise the letter and print out the capitalised 'A' used in the `letter 'A'`.

Answer (score 3):

When you want to feed the output of one function into another, this is exactly function composition, using the operator `.`:

```
(.) :: (b -> c) -> (a -> b) -> (a -> c)
```

So, you would want:

```
anyLetter :: Char -> String
anyLetter = letter . capital
```

Comment: When trying to implement this into my code, I receive the error message "Missing binding for variable "." in type signature". I understand where you are coming from using the `.` operator, though, yet I'm fairly new to Haskell and I'm trying to get grips with the whole concept of it.

Comment: @J.Hirst You don't have to copy the `(.) :: ...` line, that's already defined by Haskell. Just use the `.` operator as shown above. If you do copy the type annotation, Haskell assumes you are redefining the standard operator, and will complain if you do not so later on.

Comment: Ah, thank you, I understand. The program seems to be working again without any issues, however when I input `letter 'a'` the program can't seem to recognise what I am entering into it. I can't say I've seen the error which it is giving me, either. "pattern match failure: letter 'a'".

Comment: @J.Hirst You're only testing for the letter 'A'. Make a back-up case. But this is *not* the place to ask this, try [LYAH](http://learnyouahaskell.com/).